# Rebuilding tables from the ground up or updating the content?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a browser based game in JavaScript.
It contains a lot of Information visualized via tables.
The game is turn-based, so whenever a turn is completed, I need to adjust a lot of `innerHTML` of those tables.

My question is:

Is it smarter to give IDs to all the `<td>` and update the `innerHTML` or is it smarter to wrap the tables inside a `div`, clear the `div` and rebuild all tables from scratch, then append them?

Comment: The [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page will help you avoid downvotes :) Asking a good question is difficult. Can you quantify what you mean by *smarter*? Are you looking for performance, or in terms of code complexity? An example of your code would go a long way too

Comment: I don't know how complex your game is, but you may consider using something like React or Angular.JS if it's not a really simple game. They handle stuff like that very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how long a view stays active, if the view is shared, how many cells change and how frequently.

If you have a high number users looking at different views/pages that stay active for a long time, then it might produce less load on your servers if you can make infrequent updates to individual cells.

If the changes happen less frequent and a high proportion of cells change, then it may be best to refresh the whole table.  This would be 'less chatty' and use less network bandwidth overall.

However if you have a high number of users, all looking at the same view/page, you may wish to look into CQRS and caching your views or view data.

Answer (score 0):

Rather replace the innerHTML, the code will look nicer and it will be a lot more effortless, because instead of recreating the whole thing you would just be replacing a string in an object, which is obviously a lighter task. So in most cases it makes sense to do that.
Consider using a framework or templates, though.